# Should the same laining procedure be followed for errors outside the aliyah as the ones during the aliyah?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, torah-reading, sefer-torah

According to [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 143:4 (Mechaber)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.143.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), if someone finds a mistake in the Torah during the aliyah he is reading, he should stop, take out another Torah, finish the aliyah, and have the *oleh* say the ending bracha.

Does this same procedure apply if the reader discovers an error outside the current aliyah being read, e.g. before or after the current aliyah?

Answer (score 1):

An error found in a Sefer Torah renders the sefer pasul regardless of where it is found. The passage that you cited in the Shulchan Arukh does not seem to differentiate between a mistake in the part being read and another part, so I cannot imagine why the same procedure would not be followed in that case.

I would understand the instruction "ומתחילין ממקום שנמצא הטעות" to mean from the place where the ba'al koreh was holding at the time that he found the error.